# Facebook Marketing API - Get Page ID by Account without Ads

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to automate Ad and Creative creation across a number of accounts.  Some of these accounts will be empty, with no existing Campaigns/AdSets/Ads/Creatives.

With a given `ad_account_id`, is there any way pull all associated `page_ids`?

If not, is there any way to pull all `page_ids` associated with my user?

In the UI I have 79 page options when I create an ad, but when I try to `get_pages()`, nothing is returned:

```
In [11]: me = objects.AdUser(fbid='me')
In [12]: pages = me.get_pages()
In [13]: len(pages)
Out[13]: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Ad Accounts and Pages are associated with a person (or a System User). You can create ads for any Page in any of your Ad Accounts.

To list all the Pages associated with your user_id, you need `manage_pages` permission in your token. That's probably what you're missing.
You can try it on Graph Explorer: `me?fields=accounts`

For more info, check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/